# Is it possible to take multiple bonus actions in a single turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, action-economy

There are ways to gain multiple actions in a turn through for example the fighters action surge, but I've found nothing in respect to bonus actions.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Please review the linked question and see whether it addresses your question; if not, feel free to edit your question to explain how your issue is distinct. Otherwise, duplicate questions are just fine - they help others discover the existing question. Hope you stick around! :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the answer, couldn't find it when searching 'multiple bonus actions'